# Prohibit design refresh on WebContent

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I've been playing around with JQuery and been storing the js files in a folder under the WebContent. This database inherit it's design for a base template database.  On a design fresh this removes the content of the WebContent folder.  Is there a method to prohibit the design refresh on WebContent folder and other elements found in the Package Explorer.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the menu File:Application:Set Prohibit Refresh Properity...
Set the checkbox Prohibit design refresh or design replace to modify the selected elements
Select the element to prohibit refresh

Using version 8.5.3 FP4